# Angular validation not sync with HTML validation

Tags: angular, validation

I got an issue with Angular validation.

I have a nested modelGroup in a parentForm. In the parentForm there is a max value used in the nested modelGroup as a directive input for maximum value of the zip field.

Example in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/91k00-nested-from-validity

**Expected result:**
Once you change the max value, the max directive evaluate the zip field and invalidate the field, then the modelGroup and the parentForm are invalid too.

[image]

**Actual result:** 
Once you change the max value, the max directive evaluate the zip field and invalidate the field *but the modelGroup and parentForm are still valid*.

[image]

Could you explain me this behaviour and help me to fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: perhaps you could manually set the `myForm.valid` prop to `false` in this case.

Comment: I would suggest reactive form instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give Angular a break. You change the maxValue, and inmediatly make the update. Use a SetTimeout to make a new cicle

```
  updateValidity() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.parentForm.controls.address.controls["zip"].updateValueAndValidity();
    })
  }
```

Futhermore, you need call to function updateValidity when you change the value;

```
setTo899 () {
    this.maxZipValue = 899;
    this.updateValidity()
  }
```

And

```
<input type="number" name="maxZipValue" 
     [ngModel]="maxZipValue" 
     (ngModelChange)="maxZipValue=$event;updateValidity()">
```

see [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/91k00-nested-from-validity-g4iosw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: I don't be sure, but using ReactiveForms can be work best and it's possible remove this work-around

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should start thinking about migrating to Reacive Forms...